# Spring Boot JPA with several DBs (H2)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

My application needs connecting to several databases.
Therefore, following several sources, the end result to connect to 2 H2 databases using spring jpa is the following  :

application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    db1:
      jdbc-url: jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MYSQL
      username: sa
      password: password
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    db2:
      jdbc-url: jdbc:h2:mem:db2;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MYSQL
      username: sa
      password: password
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.test.db1.repo"})
public class Db1Config {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.db1")
  public DataSource db1DataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.test.db2.repo"})
public class Db2Config {

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.db2")
  public DataSource db2DataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
}
```

When running such application, I can connect to the 2 H2 dbs via the h2-console.

Now, I would like to load some initial data to the dbs.

With one db, creating schema.sql and data.sql files in the resources folder allows loading initial data.

With two dbs, only the primary db get initialized.

Apparently there used to be 2 configurations

```yaml
spring:datasource:schema: classpath:schema.sql
spring.datasource.data: classpath:data.sql
```

which would have allowed to specify the files to load for each db but the following error is generated eventhough the file exists in resources/:

```
2022-11-07 15:38:04,363 | ERROR | [main] | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool |  | HikariPool-2 - Error thrown while acquiring connection from data sourceorg.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "classpath:schema.sql" not found [90079-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:632)

2022-11-07 15:38:04,363 | ERROR | [main] | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool |  | HikariPool-2 - Exception during pool initialization.org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "classpath:schema.sql" not found [90079-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:632)
```

According to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7.0-Configuration-Changelog, the properties have been removed and replaced by:

```yaml
spring:sql:init:schema-locations: classpath:schema.sql
spring:sql:init:data-locations: classpath:data.sql
```

but how could I use them to specify which db the schema and data files should be applied to?

Is there some other properties which could be used to configure that with the properties file?

What would be another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could provide `schema.sql` and `data.sql` via extra properties

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    db1:
      jdbc-url: jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MYSQL
      username: sa
      password: password
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    db2:
      jdbc-url: jdbc:h2:mem:db2;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MYSQL
      username: sa
      password: password
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
# schema and data scripts
db1:
  schema: scripts/db1_schema.sql
  data: scripts/db1_data.sql
db2:
  schema: scripts/db2_schema.sql
  data: scripts/db2_data.sql
```

and provide 2 `DatabasePopulator` beans

```java
// in Db1Config 
@Bean
public DatabasePopulator dataSourceInitializer1(
           DataSource db1DataSource, 
           @Value("${db1.schema}") String schemaLocation, 
           @Value("${db1.data}") String dataLocation){
    Resource schema= new ClassPathResource(schemaLocation);
    Resource data = new ClassPathResource(dataLocation);
    DatabasePopulator dbPopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(schema, data);
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(dbPopulator, db1DataSource);
    return dbPopulator;
}
    

// in Db2Config
@Bean
public DatabasePopulator dataSourceInitializer2(
           DataSource db2DataSource, 
           @Value("${db2.schema}") String schemaLocation, 
           @Value("${db2.data}") String dataLocation){
    Resource schema= new ClassPathResource(schemaLocation);
    Resource data= new ClassPathResource(dataLocation);
    DatabasePopulator dbPopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(schema, data);
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator, db1DataSource);
    return dbPopulator;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. It is working only after adding @Qualifier to the DataSource beans declaration and to their corresponding parameters in DatabasePopulator beans. Otherwise, only the primary database gets populated.

Comment: `@Qualifier` is not needed if you use the matching names as parameters: `db1DataSource` and  `db2DataSource`. But I agree, using `@Qualifier` will make the code more understandable/readable and safer for refactoring.